# Submit form via AJAX in jQuery doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, send

I using following jQuery code to submit a form via AJAX.

```
$(function(){
    $("#forma_upis").submit(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:$(this).attr("action"),
            type:$(this).attr("method"),
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            success:function(data){

            $("#Formcontent").fadeOut('slow');
            /*$("#content").load("stranice/lista_upis.php");*/

            if(data==1)
                {
                    $("#content").load("stranice/lista_upis.php");
                }
                else
                {
                alert(data);
                    alert("Error!!!");
                }

            }


        });

        return false;
    });

})
```

This work on my PC but when I try this on my other PC it doesn't work and I get an error and dont send data.

Comment: What are the differences between the PCs? Browser? Do you get any javascript errors in the console? And when you say you get "Error??" do you get the alert? If so just echo out 'data' and you will get an error message containing information abou what went wrong.

Comment: is the back-end process available to both PC's?  Like, is there a firewall or anything that is in the way?

Comment: do you have stranice/lista_upis.php in other pc ?

Comment: I get error from alert.When i echo data i dont get anything ,its empty.No firewall and there is no diferences betwean i just copyed folder with everything.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you have to look some things, like:

1) Are you you linking the JQuery library correctly in the other PC?

2) In the other PC do you have the php file (stranice/lista_upis.php)?

3) The server-side is working in the other PC?

Hope it helps...